# ASP.NET MVC Views Dependency Injection without DependencyResolver?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap, multi-tenant

Is it possible to inject dependencies into an MVC ViewPage (must support layout pages) without using DependencyResolver?

I would rather not use DependencyResolver at all (I had major problems when injecting NH sessions into ActionFilters in the past (leaking all over the place)). However, I'm not sure if there is an alternative?

The other complexity I have is that the DependencyResolver needs to be tenant aware (each tenant has its own (StructureMap) container). I'm currently doing this by passing in a lazy instance of my tenant container resolver (seems this is necessary otherwise the resolver is cached):

```
public SmDependencyResolver(Func<ISiteContainerResolver> containerResolver)
{
    this.containerResolver = containerResolver;
}

public object GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    var container = containerResolver().Resolve();
```

If I end up using DependencyResolver should I ditch my StructureMap controller factory since it looks like DependencyResolver handles this too?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the DependencyResolver is used by so many aspects of the ASP.NET MVC framework for dependency injection your life will be easier if you use it - as you say it means you don't need your own versions of things like the controller factory.

That said, the framework is very flexible and it is always open for you to plug in your own version of things - I just prefer to create as little of my own code as possible on the KISS principle.